# Merging code branch to master using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am new in TortoiseGit. I created one branch named `Angular`. Now I want to merge that code into `master`, but I don't know how can I merge code branch `Angular` to `master` using TortoiseGit(not using command prompt).

Comment: Switch to master first, then merge that other branch.

Comment: See details in https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-merge.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Switch to the master branch.

Right click in the directory you have your repo, go to TortoiseGit->Merge.

Select the branch your want to merge into master, then put in your merge message, hit ok

1. Checkout Master
2. TortoiseGit->Merge
3. Select branch you want to merge, hit ok

Comment: I would also suggest choosing one of the **Strategy** choices. I forgot to do that a few times and ended up with some very confusing results. Not sure if it was a fluke or if not choosing a strategy actually does something different. I would think it would simply default to **resolve** (which is the most common strategy).

Comment: Am using bitbucket-git.  when using TortoiseGit tool to Merge. Successfully merged but am able to see merge in local. But not able to see the merge in bitbucket web view. Any idea?