# How to get update from Master to branch in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have checked out the `master` version from remote repository and did switch to branch named `dev`. Now I did some changes in `dev` branch which need to be pushed into `dev` remote branch. But I need to have a sync and updates from `master` too before pushing my changes into `dev` branch.

Help me how to achieve this in TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 5):

## Merge

1. Switch/Checkout to "master"
2. Pull
3. Switch/Checkout to "dev"
4. Right click on "master" branch, and Merge to "dev"
5. Push dev

## Rebase

1. Fetch origin
2. Right click on "origin/master" and Rebase "dev" onto this...
3. Start Rebase
4. Push dev

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so in order to merge the master to branch was like do the merge branch to master.

**TIP**: before you get update from master to realize the merge you should:

- update your local repository (master) before to switch to your branch;
- switch to your branch;
- peform the `stash save`;

Peform the merge, so:

- peform the `stash pop`;
- solve the conflits;
- perform the `push`;
- perform the `commit`;

Otherwise the changes made at master wont go to branch.

See also: [Merging code branch to master using tortoisegit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202072/merging-code-branch-to-master-using-tortoisegit)