# How can I override the default (long) commit message on a squash merge in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Most of our team is using TortoiseGit.  We do feature development on branches, and merge master into the feature branch (and test) right before landing the branch back to master.  We tell people to do a squash merge to keep the history clean.  (Maybe that's our mistake?)

Instead of the default commit message (a concatenation of all commit messages from master since branch start or the last merge), we would like to be able to write a shorter commit message (basically, saying it was a squash merge and then describing any notable conflict resolutions).  The problem is that for a squash merge, TortoiseGit does not allow the commit message to be edited.

Is there a way to change that behavior in TortoiseGit -- to do a squash merge with the commit message being editable?  I know we can do this from the command line (and I often do myself), but some team members are more comfortable with the GUI and I'd like to be able to support them with it if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check "No commit" (as well as squash) on the merge dialog and then open the commit dialog to edit the pre-filled commit text.

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/Merge.png]

PS: You might also be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795779/3906760. When squashing one loses history and you get also get a clean history with rebasing and non-fast-forward merging.