# How to incluce source branch name as part of message when use TortoiseGit Cherry Pick

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-cherry-pick

in TortoiseSVN, when merge commits from one branch to another branch path, it will auto generate message with source branch, E.g. "Merge revision(s) [revision] from [branch path]:"

how i can get same feature in TortoiseGit Cherry Pick? 
currently in TortoiseGit Cherry Pick has one option "add 'cherry picked from'", if i check this option, it will add SHA-1 as part of message. 
E.g. (cherry picked from commit xxxxxxxx)

is any option make it be source branch? E.g. (cherry picked from [branch path]: commit xxxxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature. I suppose the reason is, that a commit can be on multiple branches at the very same time, also in Git branches are mostly just local.

Please note, that cherry-picking is not the same as merging.

When you merge with TortoiseGit/Git you can also get a merge commit ("merged from branch x") automatically if the branch does not fast-forward on the other branch or on special request, cf. [Correctly merging a feature branch using TortoiseGit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41794529/3906760).

Comment: thanks @MrTux, understand cherry pick is not same as merge, sometime i'd like to develop code within one branch for few feature, instead of create new branch for each feature (because no much code change), also it will reduce effort about merge back the master to each develop branch after master released. 

not sure is any workaround to achieve this, or any other tools suppport this. otherwise need edit the commit message after cherry pick complete each time.