# Different results when merging branches Via Azure Devops and Locally using GIT

Tags: git, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

I came across an issues I am not sure about and was wondering if someone could explain it to me.  First, let me explain the issue.

I have two branches:

- **Master**
- **Release/MyRelease**

I wish to merge the **Master** branch into the **Release/MyRelease** branch.  I tested two different strategies of doing this and was expecting the results to be the same.

Strategy 1:

Via Azure Devops, Create a new Pull Request that merges **Master** Directly into **Release/MyRelease**

Strategy 2:

Locally, using Tortoise git to create a new branch called **TempMergeBranch** off **Release/MyRelease**
and then merge **Master** into that branch.  Next created a pull request in Azure Devops to merge **TempMergeBranch** into **Release/Mybranch**

Generally I would use strategy 2 if there were merge conflicts.

Expected Results would be by using either of the two strategies above, I would get the same output as long as there are no merge conflicts.

What is happening is I am getting certain files with different merge results when using strategy 1 vs strategy 2.  Azure Devops seems to be leaving changes out of the **Release/MyRelease** branch when merging.

Not sure why this is happening, perhaps there is a different merge strategy used in local git vs Azure Devops?  Any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: Have you checked whether your local `Release/MyRelease` is up to date ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yep, all of the branches are up to date

Comment: Please check if there is a commit of the TempMergeBranch to Master, you could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794529/correctly-merging-a-feature-branch-using-tortoisegit?noredirect=1&lq=1